# ASP.NET processing unauthenticated file request in site with Windows Authentication: How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

I have a curious problem with a legacy ASP.NET web application using Windows Authentication. A particular page is crashing, and an inspection of the page and the site logs indicates the page is crashing because the request is not properly authenticated - no Windows identity is being requested by IIS or supplied by IE 11.

The page has a curious path; it took a few minutes to decode how it was originally assembled. The initial request is not for a specific page, but is merely a folder-only URL that is routed to Default.aspx. The handler checks the query string and redirects to specific pages accordingly.

The initial request to the site is authenticated, as evidenced by the IIS site logs. The page to which the request is redirected (Response.Redirect) does *not* authenticate. The absence of the Windows authentication challenge leaves the site with no automatic identity to the targeted page, leading to the page crash (code depending on the identity fails). The sequence goes this way:

1. Original URL: /sitename/folder/?parameter1=value&parameter2=value
2. IIS issues the authentication challenge, and the authenticated user is shown in the logs - eg, domain\user
3. The request is then handled by folder/Default.aspx (default page as defined in IIS)
4. Default.aspx.cs inspects the query string, and routes the request to (eg) OtherPage.aspx via Response.Redirect.
5. OtherPage.aspx is requested, and the request is logged - with no authentication, and no challenge
6. OtherPage.aspx.cs crashes (no user credential)

I am trying to theorize how or why ASP.NET is even permitting the unauthenticated file request. I have tried to reproduce the behavior in a test environment, and have been unable to do so. I have suspected that "Automatic logon in Intranet zone" might have been disabled, or that stored local credentials may be present but somehow causing a conflict, but neither of those scenarios panned out. The former *did* result in a failed authentication attempt and a proper 401 response from the server (the target page was not fired in a test environment).

Comment: What do you mean by "routes"? 302-redirects? Also, the ntlm or kerberos is used?

Comment: I have amended the text to answer the "route/302" question. I have not yet done a wire trace to determine NTLM vs Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

Further research into this question has led to a solution if not a 100% dissection of the cause.

The users experiencing the problem were accessing the target site via a link in an email message. The link, for some unknown reason, inhibited the credential exchange between IE and IIS until the site URL was placed in the "Local Intranet" sites list of IE. This allowed the "Automatic logon in Intranet sites only" option to apply which, in turn, allowed the authentication to work.

The reason this is not a "100% dissection" is because these users were accessing the site previously, wherein authentication worked when the site was accessed conventionally. Exactly how the email message link inhibited the authentication exchange is not known. At the moment, I theorize that some security setting inhibits authentication when originating from an email link unless the specific site URL is *explicitly* qualified as a trusted or Intranet site.

Thanks for your consideration.